# How to mock a @HostListener event in Angular without Testbed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

Given is a (extremely simplified) component with a drop zone, standard angular in typescript. Tests are to be written for the handlers, like:

```
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  dragover(event: DragEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Now it's simple to test the function itself if I ignore the calling hostlistener:

```
  describe('METHOD: dragover', () => {

    test('should call event.preventDefault', () => {
      const event = { type: 'dragover', preventDefault: jest.fn()} as unknown as DragEvent;
      const spy = jest.spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');

      sut.dragover(event);

      expect(sut).toBeTruthy();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Of course that would qualify as a very basic unit test, and "skipping" on that tiny @HostListener decorator might still allow me to "proudly" reach the coverage treshhold. But let's pretend we write those tests to REALLY do their job, and not just meet some bottom lines.

So what I probably need to do is supply the component with a function to emit the event. I researched several ways to do so, from the direct approach to the more convoluted (supply a rendered mock template, that holds the emitter) but seem to miss some obvious step. Isn't there a simple way to mock an event emitter that "calls" above functions?

PS: Yes, I'm aware this is simple with Testbed. I'm intentionally refraining from using it for three reasons (so please keep your hatchets buried):

a) our customer explicitely ordered unit-tests, not integration tests (the distinction surely being debatable), but more importantly

b) an increase of the test-time by a factor of 2-10 is inacceptable given 10k+ tests, and to make things worse

c) my tests are to be used as "How To"s by junior devs, so my own tests have to be as conscient and clear as possible. I tried explaining to them WHEN its fine to use TestBed, and why and when not to do it... but in the end they still always used the "testbed-hammer"

And yes, I'm aware of libraries that allow shallow rendering, and/or wrap around TestBed, hiding it away and de-bloating it. Further hints in that direction are surely welcome, though I'd prefer to understand the "manual" way myself first, before I use the "shortcuts". Makes it easier to explain the hows and whys to our interns and juniors. ;)